# Manage ssh_known_hosts with puppet

Tags: linux, puppet, ssh-keys, puppetdb

I'm new to [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) (open source version) and have a relatively straightforward question.

When I bring up a new host, I'd like the puppetmaster to add the new host's public rsa key to /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts, and so the updated ssh_known_hosts file will be available to be pulled down by puppet agents.

I've tried the `sshkey` resource:

```
# /etc/puppet/modules/ssh/manifests/client.pp

sshkey { $hostname:
    ensure => present,
    type => "rsa",
    key  => $sshrsakey,
}
```

However, ssh_known_hosts does not appear to be modified on the puppetmaster, or agent for that matter.  My manifest passes syntax validation when I run `puppet parser validate client.pp` and running `puppet agent --test` on the agent does not report any issues.

Do I have to have [Stored Configs](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Using_Stored_Configuration) set up in order to use the sshkey resource?  I like the features of Stored Configs, but it seems like overkill for what I need and seems to add lots of overhead.  My other option is to spit the `$sshrsakey` fact to a `file`, but it will need to check for the existence of the public key so it doesn't get added more than once.

Comment: If you're not using PuppetDB (the next generation of Storeconfigs), you might want to look at that. http://puppetlabs.com/blog/introducing-puppetdb-put-your-data-to-work The API given in the above answer doesn't change, but you'll get a performance gain. Note that this requires Puppet 2.7.12 or higher.

Comment: Wow that was literally released the other day.  Thanks for the tip, I'm sure I'll be making use of puppetdb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you need to have stored configs enabled.

On each host, you'll want to collect the keys into the stored configs database (note the `@@`):

```
@@sshkey { $hostname:
    ensure => present,
    type => "rsa",
    key  => $sshrsakey,
}
```

Then, you'll want to write them to the file on each host as well.

```
Sshkey <<| |>>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Can I have other host entries in ssh_known_hosts that are not managed by Puppet?  I'm just wondering how Puppet manages this file and if it gets overwritten with nothing but Puppet agent keys.  I'm sure I can answer it myself once I do some testing with PuppetDB here shortly, but that may be a few days before I get into it.

Comment: @Banjer see http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#sshkey. Further, it only edits the file to add or remove (`ensure => absent`) the related line. It will not clobber the file by default, so you should be able to add any other keys you wish outside of Puppet if you desire.

Comment: It clobbered my file. (*restoring from backup*)